# How to pass special characters in a URL

Tags: php, url, character-encoding

I am trying to send a classic GET request to an API : http://mywebsite.com?arg1=val1&arg2=val2.
The problem is I don't know what to do if **val1** or **val2** contains a "&" or "?" character. I know the *urlencode()* function but I'm not sure it would help in this case as there needs to be a difference between the "&" used to separate the arguments and the "&" contained by the arguments.

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a much simpler solution. *urlencode()* did the trick:

```
$url = 'http://mywebsite.com?arg1='.urlencode('val1').'arg2='.urlencode('val2').......
```

Thank you all for your replies.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could try to use `http_build_query()`.

http://php.net/http_build_query

```
$data = array('foo'=>'bar',
              'baz'=>'a&c',
              'cow'=>'d?f');

echo http_build_query($data); // foo=bar&baz=a%26c&cow=d%3Ff
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't tried it but this should work. I used a simpler code with urlencode() though.

Answer (score 1):

if you pass these variables manually, you should urlencode(), if not, browser will do this for you automatically.

Also, for PHP side, no need to urldecode() because PHP will do it for $_GET, $_COOKIE, $_POST

Answer (score 1):

I would personally do this:

```
$your_array = array('1'=>'something', '2'=>'another thing!');
$send_in_url = json_encode($your_array);
$send_in_url = base64_encode($send_in_url);

header('Location: www.mywebsite.com?code='.$send_in_url);
```

In your API you will do:

```
$code = base64_decode($_GET['code']);
$array = json_decode($code);

echo $array[1]; // this will output "something"
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked well, I was using simple encode/decode which in general ignores ! or any other special symbol. base64_encode does this.