# how to get sign # and + in php method GET from url

Tags: php, get

Hi i want to get sign # and + from url but php not get this signs

i want to get uusd code (like *145*2568# for operator mobile)
or get the full number code country mobile like : +98 123456789

thanks

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: This question is basically the same, and has all the answers :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216315/how-to-pass-special-characters-in-a-url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass special characters in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216315/how-to-pass-special-characters-in-a-url)